# How do I use array to add an undo-list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, undo

I'm trying to make a paint-program in JavaScript, and I want to include an undo-function (not an eraser). How do I add all the events to an array, and then make it possible to delete them one by one?

I have a dropdown list of tools (only four of them are working so far). I've added an undo button with an id. I've tried for hours (days in fact) to find out how to do this. I have found some examples, and I think I'll have to use both push and an empty array to get further?

This is the code for the tool-selection and the button

```
<label>
  Object type:
    <select id="selectTool">
        <option value="line">Linje</option>
        <option value="pencil">Blyant</option>
        <option value="rect">Rektangel</option>
        <option value="circle">Sirkel</option>
        <option value="oval">Oval</option>
        <option value="polygon">Polygon</option>
    </select>

  Shape drawn:
    <select id="shapeDrawn">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>   

  <input type="button" id="cmbDelete" value="Undo last action">

</label>
```

The undo function could maybe be something like this, but this function

```
var shapes = [];
shapes.push(newShape);


 function cmbDeleteClick(){
  if(shapes.length > 0){
    var selectedShapeIndex = selectShape.selectedIndex;
    shapes.splice(selectedShapeIndex,1);
    selectShape.options.remove(selectedShapeIndex);
    selectShape.selectedIndex = selectShape.options.length - 1;
  }
    cmbDelete = document.getElementById("cmbDelete");
    cmbDelete.addEventListener("click",cmbDeleteClick, false);
    fillSelectShapeTypes();
    drawCanvas(); 
}
```

Ideally, everything that gets painted on the canvas is added to a dropdown menu, ​and it can be removed (undone) by clicking a button. Here is the "working" version of the code [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/vasivug/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation does not utilize the `shapes` array and provides no way to redraw them after they've been created.

So it's easiest to store each action as a bitmap.
So you'll need an array for the bitmaps, lets call it:

```
var history = [];
```

Once something has been drawn we create a snapshot of the current canvas and store it in that array:

```
history.push(contextTmp.getImageData(0,0,canvasTmp.width,canvasTmp.height))
```

When you want to undo a action, pop the history and draw the last bitmap on canvas:

```
function cmbDeleteClick(){
    history.pop()
    contextTmp.putImageData(history[history.length-1],0,0)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Paint</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #content { position: relative; }
  #cvs { border: 1px solid #c00; }
  #cvsTmp { position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  
<label>
Object type:
 <select id="selectTool">
  <option value="line">Linje</option>
  <option value="pencil">Blyant</option>
  <option value="rect">Rektangel</option>
  <option value="circle">Sirkel</option>
  <option value="oval">Oval</option>
  <option value="polygon">Polygon</option>
 </select>
 
Shape drawn:
 <select id="shapeDrawn">
  <option value=""></option>
 </select> 
 
History:
 <select id="historySelect">
 </select> 
  
<input type="button" id="cmbDelete" value="Undo last action">

</label>

</p>
 
<div id="content">
 <canvas id="cvs" width="1024" height="512"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 
if(window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var canvas;
  var context;
  var canvasTmp;
  var contextTmp;

  var tool;
  var toolDefault = 'line';
 
  var cmbDelete = null;
  var shapes = [];
  var history = [];
  var historySelect;

// Canvas and temp. canvas
 
function init () {
    canvasTmp = document.getElementById('cvs');
   if (!canvasTmp) {
    return;
   } if (!canvasTmp.getContext) {
      return;
    }
    
    historySelect = document.getElementById('historySelect')
    historySelect.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
      restoreHistoryAction(historySelect.value)
    })

    contextTmp = canvasTmp.getContext('2d');
   if (!contextTmp) {
    return;
   }

    // Add the temporary canvas.
    var content = canvasTmp.parentNode;
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    if (!canvas) {
      return;
    }

    canvas.id     = 'cvsTmp';
    canvas.width  = canvasTmp.width;
    canvas.height = canvasTmp.height;
    content.appendChild(canvas);

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  

    // Get the tool select input.
    var toolSelect = document.getElementById('selectTool');
    if (!toolSelect) {
      return;
    }
    toolSelect.addEventListener('change', ev_tool_change, false);

    // Activate the default tool.
    if (tools[toolDefault]) {
      tool = new tools[toolDefault]();
      toolSelect.value = toolDefault;
    }

    // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', evMouse, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', evMouse, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   evMouse, false);
  
    drawCanvas()
  }

function evMouse (ev) {
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) {
      ev._x = ev.layerX;
      ev._y = ev.layerY;
    }
 var evHandler = tool[ev.type];
 if (evHandler) {
  evHandler(ev);
 }
}
 
  // The event handler for any changes made to the tool selector.
  function toolChange (ev) {
    if (tools[this.value]) {
      tool = new tools[this.value]();
    }
  } 
 
 
  // Updates Canvas on interval timeout
function drawCanvas() {
 contextTmp.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    history.push(contextTmp.getImageData(0,0,canvasTmp.width,canvasTmp.height))
    updateHistorySelection()
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
 
  function ev_tool_change (ev) {
    if (tools[this.value]) {
      tool = new tools[this.value]();
    }
  }

  // Get excact position for mouse coordinates in canvas
  function mouseAction (ev) {
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) {
      ev._x = ev.layerX;
      ev._y = ev.layerY;
    }

    // Call the event handler of the tool.
    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
      func(ev);
    }
  }


  function selectShapeChange(){
    drawCanvas();
  }
 
 

 
 
 var tools = {};

  // The drawing pencil.
  tools.pencil = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        tool.started = true;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        context.stroke();
      }
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
        drawCanvas();
      }
    };
  };
 
// The rectangle tool.
  tools.rect = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
      tool.started = true;
      tool.x0 = ev._x;
      tool.y0 = ev._y;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (!tool.started) {
        return;
      }

      var x = Math.min(ev._x,  tool.x0),
          y = Math.min(ev._y,  tool.y0),
          w = Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
          h = Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0);

      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      if (!w || !h) {
        return;
      }
      context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  context.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + 360 * Math.random() + ', 50%, 50%)';
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
        drawCanvas();
      }
    };
  };

  // The line tool.
  tools.line = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
      tool.started = true;
      tool.x0 = ev._x;
      tool.y0 = ev._y;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (!tool.started) {
        return;
      }

      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(tool.x0, tool.y0);
      context.lineTo(ev._x,   ev._y);
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
        drawCanvas();
      }
    };
  };
 
// Circle tool
  tools.circle = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
      tool.started = true;
      tool.x0 = ev._x;
      tool.y0 = ev._y;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (!tool.started) {
        return;
      }

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var radius = Math.max(
Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0)
) / 2;

var x = Math.min(ev._x, tool.x0) + radius;
var y = Math.min(ev._y, tool.y0) + radius;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
// context.arc(x, y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();

};

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
        drawCanvas();
      }
 };
  };

// Ellipse/oval tool
 
// Polygon tool

// Undo button

 function cmbDeleteClick(){
    if(history.length<=1)
      return
      
    history.pop()
    contextTmp.putImageData(history[history.length-1],0,0)
    updateHistorySelection()
  }
  
  function updateHistorySelection(){
    historySelect.innerHTML = ''

    history.forEach((entry,index)=>{
      let option = document.createElement('option')
      option.value = index
      option.textContent = index===0 ? 'Beginning' : 'Action '+index
      historySelect.appendChild(option)
    })

    historySelect.selectedIndex = history.length-1
  }

  function restoreHistoryAction(index){
    contextTmp.putImageData(history[index],0,0)
  }
  
  cmbDelete = document.getElementById("cmbDelete");
  cmbDelete.addEventListener("click",cmbDeleteClick, false);

  init();

}, false); } 
 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not very efficient though. It will store a full bitmap of the canvas for every action, so it's very memory consuming. It'd be best to actually have the drawing tools create a shape instance which can be called to redraw on the canvas on demand.

Comment: Wow! This was an elegant solution that even I could understand. This might be a lot to ask, but is it even possible to somehow add the history-array as options in the dropdown menu? (shapeDrawn)

Comment: @Senseless Main problem will be the labeling for the history entries. Check the snippet again, I've coded up a quick example for it so you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is keep track of the full state of the painting before making each change, so you can restore it. So you'd have an undo array, and whenever you modify the canvas, right *before* you make the modification, you push the current canvas state onto the array (canvas.toDataURL would be very helpful to encapsulate the entire image state). Then make the modification after.

When you undo, you can pop the last element from the undo array, which will be the data URL of the canvas just before the last change, and then reset the canvas to that image. So something like this:

```
function undoLastChange() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_ID');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
  img.src = undoArray.pop();
}
```